# Facebook Messenger Chat always shows one chat unread

Tags: notifications, facebook-messenger

The Facebook Messenger app always shows a '1' next to the speech bubble indicating that there is a 'Chat' I haven't read. How can I clear this, or alternatively, find and read this supposedly unread chat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [SocMedSean's page of fixes](https://www.socmedsean.com/solved-how-do-i-clear-the-facebook-messenger-notification-when-i-dont-have-a-new-message/):

1. Open Facebook in your desktop web browser (not on mobile)
2. Click on the Messenger (speech bubble) icon
3. Click on 'Settings' (the cog)
4. Click on 'Unread Chats' - this will likely reveal some very old chats that you have never marked as 'read'
5. Click on each old chat to mark them as 'read'
6. Check back in Messenger to see if there are still unread messages showing